# How to fix inconsistent font rendering under Windows?

Tags: front-end, fonts, windows, antialiasing

The FrontEnd's font rendering in graphics is inconsistent under Windows (still using Win7). Sometimes small fonts are not antialiased, sometimes they are. See, for instance, the help page for `DefaultLabelStyle`, 2D is antialiased, 3D is not:

[image]

Explicitly specifying the same font with `LabelStyle` does not fix it:

[image]

Most annoying it becomes when using a legend in `ListDensityPlot`. The frameticks and labels on the plot are rendered differently from those on the legend. Only at large font sizes the FrontEnd starts antialiasing everything.

[image]

Obviously, the `RenderingOptions` setting for the FrontEnd is not the issue, see [this possibly related post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157693/why-are-label-pixelated). The problem is as least as old as 10.4 and still persists in 11.3 (all under Win7).

One thing I have loved about Mathematica since version 4 is the beautiful graphics I can produce, but this is a fly in the ointment.

P.S. The FrontEnd on my Raspberry Pi renders everything consistently.

Comment: Oh my.. nice question, but I'm not sure anyone except WRI can give you a solution for this :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm deleting this later if it leads to nothing, but I want to make some notes. First, and most obvious: I have the strong feeling that there are different fonts in the game. They look similar, but let me point out the differences. Here are two "1.0" from your last image

> [image: img]
>
> [image: img2]

- While the small, diagonal line of the first "1" is almost straight, it is slightly curved in the second 1
- The zero is almost rectangular in the first image but much more oval in the second image

Please look very carefully at

```
Grid[Partition[
  Table[Style["1.0", FontFamily -> f], {f, $FontFamilies}], 10, 
10, {1, 1}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And then try to set *one and the same* font in the density plot and its legend. Can you manually fix the problem?

Comment: Somehow applying `Magnify` solves the problem (Windows 7 x64): [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP7rz.png).

Comment: @Alex: Same "solution" if I use LabelStyle -> 18.

Comment: I don't think it is the font selection because if I add
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Times"} to both itmes form the DefaultLabelStyle example the issue remains. I added that to my question.